# Valid domain cannot use tunnel site

Tags: microsoft-teams, manifest.json, microsoft-graph-teams

I see the following error when trying to install my app in Teams for testing: "Valid domain cannot use tunnel site". I am using ngrok as described in the guide. So, I believe this is the reason for not being able to install the app. When I try to install it for a team, I see "Something went wrong." error and the app is not installed. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The "tunnel site" is usually shown as a warning, not an actual error, and it should work fine. Your "something went wrong" is likely something else, but you'll need give more info. Is it a bot? a Tab? Where do you see the error? Can you post a screenshot perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by using this command.

**ngrok.exe http -host-header=rewrite localhost:3979**